# Tidying up a JSON-like string with PHP and str_replace

Tags: php, string, str-replace, tidy

I am putting an inout field value into my database which is has the structure of the following string:

```
[{\"value\":\"Product 1\"},{\"value\":\"Product 2\"},{\"value\":\"Product 3\"}]
```

Now I want to make it a bit more readable in the database and strip the string from all the unnecessary characters, into something like this:

```
Product 1, Product 2, Product 3
```

I could obviously do it with the following method:

```
str_replace(',',', ',str_replace('[','',str_replace(']','',str_replace('{\"value\":\"','',str_replace('\"}','',$INPUT_FIELD)))));
```

But this feels a bit clunky. What would be a prettier solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Var dumping $_POST shows me this for the certain input field:

```
["project_products_used"]=> string(135) "[{\"value\":\"Product 1\"},{\"value\":\"Product 2\"},{\"value\":\"Product 3\"}]"
```

Comment: What? json_decode the JSON, then loop round the result. It's JSON, just with some escapes you can deal with.

Comment: Also, you should really consider using a table with more rows, and not store comma separated values like this.

Comment: I am using a library that returns this as a string, so I can not json_decode it.

Comment: You usually use json_decode() on strings...

Comment: Sure you can. `print_r(json_decode($INUPT_FIELD));` If you couldn't do that, you couldn't replace parts of the string either.

Comment: @Qirel, I am saying DB, but its basically an ACF Field for Wordpress, I just need it to echo the string on a certain page.

Comment: Use a library that gives you valid JSON then? Or strip the escapes? Or if this lib is generating this string from your data, use the data rather than the string? Either way,  what you're doing isn't really the way to go.

Comment: Please update your question instead of dumping it in the comments.

Comment: Then `print_r(json_decode($_POST['project_products_used']));`..

Comment: @Qirel somehow this returns nothing

Comment: Unable to reproduce https://3v4l.org/5hmKf

Comment: That string isn't 135 characters even with the back slashes unless it's filled with invisible characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it to array and use [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to have a string as you want:

```
<?php
$a = "[{\"value\":\"Product 1\"},{\"value\":\"Product 2\"},{\"value\":\"Product 3\"}]";
var_dump(implode(", ", array_column(json_decode($a), "value")));
```

output:

```
string(31) "Product 1, Product 2, Product 3"
```

[demo](https://www.tehplayground.com/M8h7ceAHErRVamF6)